# Second order filter

Tags: summation, filters, kalman-filter

Can I express this summation expression with the following routine logic:

$$\hat{x_{k+2}} = \sum_{i=1}^{k+2}\frac{x_i}{k+2} = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{x_i+x_{k+2}+x_{k+1}}{k+2}$$

now suppose I want to calculate the second order filter for the least squares equation, to obtain the kalman gain function.

I have attempted with this approach:

$$\hat{x_{k+2}} = \frac{k\hat{x_k} + x_{k+2} + x_{k+1}}{k+2}$$

Then I subtract the second order filter from the preceding state estimate, being the first order filter, this is given as the following equation:

$$\hat{x_{k+1}} = \hat{x_k} = \frac{x_{k+1} - \hat{x_k}}{k+1} \\
\text{OR} \\
\hat{x_{k}} = \hat{x_{k-1}} = \frac{x_{k} - \hat{x_{k+1}}}{k} 
$$
and so this becomes:
$$\hat{x_{k+2}} = \frac{\hat{x_k}(k+2) + (x_{k+2} - \hat{x_{k+1}}) + (x_{k+1} - \hat{x_k})}{k+2}$$

However, the gain leaves me with $\frac{1}{k+2}$, I was expecting a gain such as $$K_{1k} = \frac{2(2k-1)}{k(k+1)}$$